# why is my if/else not working

Tags: jquery, iframe

im trying to search my page for an iframe which doesn't have the attribute 'current' set as 'current'.

(the current attribute is set when the iframe is being used, and reset once its loaded).

I'm trying to code so that IF there is 1 or more iframes not set as current, use one of them, ELSE, create a new iframe, do some other stuff and use the new one,

but this code isn't quite working, I never trip the 'alert', so I'm never going into the ELSE part even though I know I have no iframes who's 'current' attribute isn't set,:

```
var $fi = $visible.find(".file-info");
        thisPreview = {};
        var iframes = $('iframe').filter(function (index) {
                return index == 0 || $('iframe').attr("current") == "no";
              })
        if(iframes.length >0){ //if one of the iframes hasnt got current set as current, use it
            var theSuffix = iframes.attr('id').split('_').pop();
            thisPreview[theSuffix] = $fi.prev(".image-preview");
            $(this).closest(".file-upload-form").children(".variable-hidden").attr('value',theSuffix);
            iframes.attr('current','current');
            $(this).closest('.file-upload-form').attr('target','upload_target_'+theSuffix);
        }
        else{//else, create a new iframe, quick!
            var count = $('[id^="upload_target_"]').length();
            alert(count);
            var countPlus1 = count+1;
            iframe = $('<frame>').attr({'id':'upload_target_'+countPlus1,'name':'upload_target_'+countPlus1,'current':'current'}).addClass('upload-target');
            iframe.appendTo($('#container'));
            thisPreview[countPlus1] = $fi.prev(".image-preview");
            $(this).closest(".file-upload-form").children(".variable-hidden").attr('value',countPlus1);
            $(this).closest('.file-upload-form').attr('target','upload_target_'+countPlus1);

        }
```

Comment: That filter function at the top looks suspect.  Maybe you should use `$(this)` (select the current element being tested for filtering) instead of `$('iframe')` (select every iframe in the page).  Even better, just use `this.getAttribute('current') == 'no'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index == 0` will return `true` for the first iframe, regardless of whether it has that attribute or not.

Also, `$('iframe').attr("current") == "no";` selects *all* iframes. You want the current one:

```
$(this).attr("current") == "no";
```

Finally, don't make up your own attributes. Use the `data-` prefix:

```
<div data-stuff="foo"></div>
```

And the `.data()` method:

```
$('div').data('stuff') // "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Attribute Not Equal Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

```
var iframes = $('iframe[current != "current"]')
if (iframes.length > 0) {
    // use old one
} else {
    // create new one
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYtWb/) for testing.

Comment: Alternatively, use `:not([current="current"])` for better performance (per the docs @Olaf linked).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this code is giving the proper results?

```
return index == 0 || $('iframe').attr("current") == "no";
```

I'm confused by the use of the return. Will it return the evaluation of "index == 0" or will it evaluate "index == 0", if it's false then evaluate "$('iframe').attr("current") == "no"" ? I think you want it to do the latter, but it seems ambiguous and it might not be giving you the results you're expecting.